# Flutter: Add Watermark Over Video

Tags: flutter, firebase, video, ffmpeg, video-watermarking

There are some older questions on this topic, but none of them seem to have a straight forward solution. I have a flutter project that is using Firebase as the backend. Has anyone had success adding watermarks to an uploaded video? If so, which package did you use and what commands overlayed the watermark? It seems the `ffmpeg` package may be used for this type of manipulation, but the Readme is very confusing and it isn't clear if this is possible.

Comment: Try stack widget

Comment: @YeasinSheikh I am looking to add the watermark to the video file, not just in app. Similar to adding a watermark to an image, but in this case, a video that could be shared to other platforms.